# CKEDITOR doesnt initialize second time

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I updated to latest CKEDITOR 4.10 and its currently loading editor inside bootstrap modal. It loads the first time and doesn't show up on the second click. I tried `destroy()` and it still didn't work. I created a fiddle for your reference.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/harsha5085/6dfqawgk/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have checked your code. You have done small mistake.
You forgot to put $ in front of ("#modalAddBrand").

```
$("#modalAddBrand").on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
    });
```

Please let me know if this is helpful.